# Why is iteration slower than recursion in the sum function?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, recursion

I wrote a simple C++ program to time some of my functions and found out along the way that when writing the function to find the sum of all numbers from 1 to n, my iterative method was significantly slower than my recursive one. Everything I've read on the subject tells me that the opposite should be true. When I look at the assembly code here : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cajy_Y , I notice the sumR assembly is a bit shorter than sumI's , but I still can't understand how that would result in the speed difference I'm seeing.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

typedef long (*fptr)(long);

const long arg = 1000000000;

double timef(fptr f){
 auto start = clock();
 f(arg);
 auto end = clock();
 return  ((double) ( end-start )) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
}

long sumI(long num){
    long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

long sumR(long num){
    if(num == 0 || num < 0)
        return 0;
    return num+(num-1);
}

int main()
{
    cout << timef(sumI) << endl;
    cout << timef(sumR) << endl;
}
```

When compiling with:

g++ main.cpp -O3 -o recurse

./recurse

My output is:

0.898239

3e-06

Could someone explain to me what the compiler is doing to optimize the recursive function?

Comment: Probably because your recursive code isn’t recursive.

Comment: They're not using equivalent types for one thing. `long long` vs `long`.

Comment: Your "recursive code" doesn't even compute the result properly. Have you tried printing it out?

Comment: The defining feature of a recursive function is it calls itself. `sumR` doesn't call itself. It runs once and returns. That's it. That's why it's so fast.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Technically the different types won’t make a difference, they are both integral so their computation will be done in a single cycle on any modern CPU.

Comment: Probably a typo in your sumR() function -- it is not currently recursive.

Comment: If you are using a recent compiler, try adding a few `constexpr`. Compile time will rocket ... and the result will be compiled into the binariies.

Comment: If `num >= 0`, then sum is `(num * (num + 1)) / 2`. Fast and simple. No need for loop or recursivity.

Comment: @vandench **(1)** If arg is really 1000000000 then `long long` would be required if `long` is 32 bit and `long long`64 bit. **(2)** If the program is compiled in 32 bit (typical of Windows apps), then `32 bit` would be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sumR isn't recursive.  Probably a typo.

Actually, both sumR and sumI are equivalent to doing nothing, as they have no side effects and you discard the result.  So any difference could be a matter of the compiler finding it easier/harder to detect it as a noop.

When profiling, you must ensure your code actually does what you think it does.  In addition you must prove that solving the problem by doing nothing isn't an option.

Comment: Can't help but feel like an absolute idiot for not catching that.